# Modifying attribute in class method doesn't work

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I have written a simple program:

```py
import random

b = 1
count = 0
n = 0  #initialise variables

class Geek:
    def __init__(self):
      self.life = 1000 #declare attribute
  
    def countdown(self):
      self.life = self.life - b  #countdown reduces life by 1 each time at first
      global n
      n = n + random.randint(1,10)
  

while True:
  count = count + 1
  if n > 40:
    b = 10 #countdown will be faster
  uaac = Geek()
  uaac.countdown()
  if uaac.life <= 0:
    print(count) #if b doesn't change to 10 this will be 1000
    break
```

The object I created has an attribute life, which steadily ticks down through the method countdown(self) unless n, which is increased in the same method, reaches 40. In this case the attribute will reduce a lot faster as b is increased and the count printed at the end will be lower.

However for some reason I'm not getting any output - the program just runs enlessly. Why is this?

Comment: You keep creating a *new object* on each iteration. As an aside `n` should not be global. The whole *point* of a class is to encapsulate internal state!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm convinced that reinitializing inside a loop is the 2nd most common mistake that newbies make, right after using `=` when they mean `==` (except the latter isn't usually possible in Python).